# Jsonp On Server. Properly naming Json file

Tags: jquery, json

I have seen a code for a countdown timer, that goes as follows:

```
jQuery(function() {

    var days, goLive, hours, intervalId, minutes, seconds;
    goLive = function() {
        $(".countdown_timer").hide();
        return $(".live_now").show();
    };
    days = void 0;
    hours = void 0;
    minutes = void 0;
    seconds = void 0;
    intervalId = void 0;
    return $.ajax({
        url: "http://(mywebdomain.com)/json/next",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            var seconds_till;
            $("#churchonline_counter").show();
            if (typeof data.current_timestamp !== "undefined") {
                return goLive();
            } else if (typeof data.next_timestamp !== "undefined") {
                seconds_till = data.next_timestamp - (new Date().getTime() / 1000);
                hours = Math.floor((seconds_till % 86400) / 3600);
                minutes = Math.floor((seconds_till % 3600) / 60);
                seconds = Math.floor(seconds_till % 60);
                return intervalId = setInterval(function() {
                    if (--seconds < 0) {
                        seconds = 59;
                        if (--minutes < 0) {
                            minutes = 59;
                            if (--hours < 0) {
                                hours = 23;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $(".counter_h").html((hours.toString().length < 2 ? "0" + hours : hours));
                    $(".counter_m").html((minutes.toString().length < 2 ? "0" + minutes : minutes));
                    $(".counter_s").html((seconds.toString().length < 2 ? "0" + seconds : seconds));
                    if (seconds === 0 && minutes === 0 && hours === 0) {
                        goLive();
                        return clearInterval(intervalId);
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But I do not know how to create the JSON file on my web server so that it will read the data properly? 
I have tried uploading a file called "next" as a simple text file on my server using Filezilla that looked as follows:

```
({"next_timestamp":1356751800,"next_duration":3600,"next_title":"Title","next_description":"Description"})
```

But I think I am missing something on this Json uploaded file? 
I know my code works in the javascript, but the Json file I am not sure what to do with. How do I name or alter the Json file to properly have the javascript parse it?

Comment: You're JSON is invalid.. You can test it [here](http://jsonlint.com/).  Why are you wrapping it in parentheses?

Comment: Tested it without the parentheses, didn't work. Am I uploading the file correctly? Just making it a plain text file titled "json" without any end marking? And then pointing to the file that just has those simple lines of information?

Comment: yes.. try hitting it directly using the url `http://(mywebdomain.com)/json/next` and see if you see the json response

Comment: Still not working. The original code that I found had the json data wrapped in parentheses - which is why I had it wrapped. But I feel like something should go on the outside of the paratheses based on the javascript code that I provided. When I go to my web domain and follow that link, I see the json file that I uploaded on the server - it's there. It is just not reading my json file properly for some reason.

Comment: Did you try pasting the url into your browser to see if you can see the JSON response? `http://(mywebdomain.com)/json/next`  Do you see any errors in your console? if using chrome press f12

Comment: Yes, I did. I can see the JSON response. 
Try it for yourself http://www.rezasafa.com/json/next
I don't see any errors

Comment: remove the seconds_till and the paretheses and the semicolon

Comment: alright, done that. still it's not reading it.

Comment: Ok.. now you need to escape all your quote marks.. using \

Comment: I really do appreciate it though.

Comment: using \   ?    I am not sure what you mean by that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21847/discussion-between-wirey-and-jonathan-safa)

Answer (score 0):

This countdown script is written specificly for churchonlineplatform.org users and as a user of that site I can tell you that the line that reads:

```
url: "http://(mywebdomain.com)/json/next",
```

is only a sample and should actually be

```
url: "http://mywebdomain.com/json/next",
```

Hope this helps